# datetimepicker giving null value to ActionResult when greater than 12 in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have `startdate` and `enddate` column when I select date less than or equal to 12 it work fine but when i select date greater than 12 it give `nul`l value to ActionResult.

this is the function i am using.

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on("focus", ".datepicker", function () {
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
        })
    })
});
```

Text Box From view from which i am selecting date.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { placeholder = "MM-dd-yyyy", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
```

and Validation of this text box.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Start Date is required."), DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "End Date is required."), DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Change the culture on the server to one that expects dates in that format (or create a custom ModelBinder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `<system.web></system.web>` 
in your web.config file, add this line 
    `<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />`

Set culture en-GB for dd/MM/yyyy and
en-US for mm/dd/yyyy. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the datetimepicker declaration you precise a format `MM-DD-YYYY` (month-day-year) and on the EndDate property you are using `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` day/month/year.

Homogenize all your dates formats, using the same order and the same separator, and add a `DataFormatString` decorator on StartDate too